# Delphi Indy "Connect" method to a site?

Tags: delphi, indy

i have analyzed a site to see how data sent .. but i got some problem ..

the site use connect method to connect to site like this connet to "http://example.com:443" and there is no S in the http ..

there is no such method in Indy or clever compenents .. only post ,Get , put ..

this is  a pic to understand me ..

[image]

so how i can use that connect method in indy or clever compenents  .. !!

Comment: What application did you use to send a request? Little off-topic, but want to know, what app is on the screenshot, thank you @Helios

Answer (score 2):

`CONNECT` is used to let a client connect to a target server through an HTTP proxy.  This is most commonly used (but not limited) to proxying SSL connections, like those used for HTTPS.

Indy's `TIdHTTP` component uses `CONNECT` internally when you have configured a proxy Host:Port in the `TIdHTTP.ProxyParams` property and then:

1. request an HTTPS url.
2. request an HTTP url and have the `hoNonSSLProxyUseConnectVerb` flag enabled in the `TIdHTTP.HTTPOptions` property.

Indy also has a `TIdConnectThroughHttpProxy` component that can be used with Indy's other non-HTTP TCP clients to proxy connections through an HTTP proxy using `CONNECT`.

Comment: i really dont understand it right .. what should i put in host ? the site in the picture and port = 443 ? i got this info in direct connection no proxy was used and  then request same url using get ? im really confused about how i connect to http://example:443 with direct connection please help me because this will stop my project if i dont find a solution ,can you give a code example pls

Comment: All you have to do is set the `TIdHTTP.ProxyParams.ProxyServer` and `TIdHTTP.ProxyParams.ProxyPort` properties to the `Host:Port` of the **HTTP proxy** that you want to pass through. If you do not need to use an HTTP proxy, then leave them blank. Either way, you would use `TIdHTTP.Get()` and `TIdHTTP.Post()` as you normally would, specifying the **destination** HTTP/HTTPS urls as needed. `TIdHTTP` will handle the `CONNECT` internally for you.

Comment: For example, to access `https://example.com` through an HTTP proxy located at `192.168.0.100:1234`, set `ProxyServer=192.168.0.100` and `ProxyPort=1234`, then call `Get('https://example.com')` or `Post('https://example.com')` as needed.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, the following Synapse-based code would trigger a CONNECT to port 443 using the OpenSSL libraries...

```
procedure Test;

var HTTP:THTTPSend;

begin
   HTTP:=THTTPSend.Create;
   try
      HTTP.Sock.CreateWithSSL(TSSLOpenSSL);
      HTTP.Sock.SSLDoConnect;  // CONNECT happens here
      HTTP.HTTPMethod('GET','https://www.google.com/');
      (...)
   finally
      HTTP.Free;
   end;
end;
```

Comment: the site as shown in the picture it doesnt have https so will http work too ? and when i analyze the data it show the method is get, it should be conenct or it doesnt matter ! ?